# PHP - Store input values in external php array

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to store an user input from a textbox into an external php array by clicking a button. Also, there is a dependency from two radio buttons.

This is my current attempt:

At first, I include the external php array:

```
<?php
  include ('../array.php');
?>
```

The input form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="textfield" id="txt1" value="">

  <input type="radio" name="name" id="id" value="Type1">Type1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="name" id="id" value="Type2">Type2<br>

  <button id="submit" name="send" type="submit">Save</button>
</from>
```

Insert the value into the array:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['send'])){
    if (isset ($_POST['name'])){
        if ($_POST['name']=='Type1'){
            $newword = $_POST['textfield'];
            $array[] = $newword;

        }
    }
}

?>
```

But the values don't "stack", meaning that the array isn't growing with each button click.
Can anyone help please? :D

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can not have the same id for more than 1 element... -> 2 x `id="id" `

Comment: What do you mean with 'they dont "stack"'? could you provide an actual and expected result?

Comment: with stack I mean, that the items sent to array do not cumulatively stack. Like 1st button click the array is ('1'), 2nd button click its ('1','2') and so on.

Comment: remove those duplicate id attributites... use different ids or use class="whatever" 

what happens if you print_r($array); at the end of your script?

oh and fix those nested conditionals (if statements)... you can do them in one if and use &&

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stack values, you need to store them somewhere to keep values between each requests to server.

Values can be stored in session (for current user only) or in any database supported by PHP.

Here an example with session :

index.php :

```
<?php

    include ('./array.php');

?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="textfield" value="">

    <input type="radio" name="name" value="Type1">Type1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="Type2">Type2<br>

    <button id="submit" name="send" type="submit">Save</button>
</from>
```

array.php :

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!is_array($_SESSION['persistentValues'])) {
    $_SESSION['persistentValues'] = array();
}

if (isset($_POST['send']) && isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name']=='Type1') {
    $_SESSION['persistentValues'][] = $_POST['textfield'];
}

print_r($_SESSION['persistentValues']);

?>
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured it would be the easiest to store all array entries in a db.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="textfield" id="txt1" value="">
    <input type="radio" name="name" id="id" value="Type1">Type1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="name" id="id" value="Type2">Type2<br>
    <button id="submit" name="send" type="submit">Save</button>
</from>
```

in the file php put this

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST['send']) && $_POST['textfield'] && $_POST['name']){
       if ($_POST['name']=='Type1'){
           array = require('./array.php');
           $newword = $_POST['textfield'];
           $array[] = $newword;
       }
   }

 ?>
```

Comment: I get this message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting '('  regarding line with "array = require..."

Comment: I am sorry please add $array = require('../array.php');

Comment: _$array = require('../array.php');..._ ?? Really?

Comment: please require file array.php ok try this require('./array.php')